# How can I find the location of a Terminal command and how can I select a different version of it?

Tags: macos, terminal, mac

If I type `dart` in my terminal, this will access my dart terminal app.  What does this point to and where can I change it?

My `$PATH` variable is as follows:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/[USERNAME]/installs/flutter/bin:/Users/[USERNAME]/installs/connectIqSDK/bin
```

Comment: `type dart` will show you the path to the binary. Not sure what you mean by "changing it". Can you please clarify and also add how exactly you installed `dart` in the first place?

Comment: Thank you @nohillside, so there is a dart sdk included in flutter and a dart sdk installed by brew.  I would like to use the dart binary that is included in the flutter install directory.  Currently the dart command is pointing to the one installed in (/usr/local/bin/pub) and I would like to point it to ~/installs/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart

Comment: actually it is the pub command I would like to change, not the dart command (sorry, I'm a bit new to macs, I think in windows it is just an environment variable change...not too sure though)

Comment: Please edit your question to ask what you actually want to know. Also run `echo $PATH` in Terminal and add the result to the question.

Comment: PS: Matter of terminology: A command isn't pointing to a path, it is installed *in* a directory (`/usr/local/bin` and `~/installs/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin` in your case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the path to a binary by using `type`:

```
$ type latex ruby dart
latex is /Library/TeX/texbin/latex
ruby is /usr/bin/ruby
-bash: type: dart: not found
```

To use a version of a binary stored somewhere else you can

- use the full path when calling it:  `~/installs/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart`
- define an alias (won't work in scripts): `alias dart=~/installs/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart`
- adjust `PATH`: `PATH=~/installs/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:$PATH`

Comment: You can also use `which`, e.g.: `which latex ruby dart`

Comment: @user3439894 `which is aliased to 'type -p'`, at least in Bash :-)

Comment: On my system, running **macOS High Sierra**, `which which` _returns_ `/usr/bin/which` and `ls -l /usr/bin/which` _returns_ `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  18576 May 29  2018 /usr/bin/which` and this is a _binary executable_, not a _symlink_ to `type`.

Comment: @user3439894 Right you are. And here I sit now, wondering why I added an alias for this in my .bashrc.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the builtin `type` command with `-a` option to display all locations containing an executable named `NAME`.

So, to find all the locations in the `PATH` variable that points to the executable named `dart`, you can type:

```
type -a dart
```

Running `type` command without `-a` option would only display the first match found in the `PATH`.